# Python thread.join(timeout) not timing out

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I am using threading python module. I want to execute a function which runs an expression entered by a user. I want to wait for it to finish execution or until a timeout period is reached. The following code should timeout after 5 second, but it never times out.

```
def longFunc():
    # this expression could be entered by the user
    return 45 ** 10 ** 1000
 
thread = threading.Thread(target=longFunc, args=(), daemon=True)
thread.start()
thread.join(5.0)
print("end") # never reaches this point :(
```

Why is this and how can I fix this behaviour? Should I try to use multiprocessing instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect in this case you're hitting an issue where the `join` can't execute while the global interpreter lock is held by the very long-running calculation, which I believe would happen as a single atomic operation. If you change `longFunc` to something that happens over multiple instructions, such as a busy loop, e.g.

```
def longFunc():
    while True:
        pass
```

then it works as expected. Is the single expensive calculation realistic for your situation or did the example just happen to hit a very bad case?

Using the `multiprocessing` module does appear to resolve this issue:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def longFunc():
    # this expression could be entered by the user
    return 45 ** 10 ** 1000

if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread = Process(target=longFunc, args=(), daemon=True)
    thread.start()
    thread.join(5.0)
    print("end")
```

This prints `"end"` as expected.

Comment: Well the thing is the user will be entering expressions, any bad expressions should be dealt with,  if not then the whole workflow is blocked and this is not desired. (the expressions are dealt with server side and this obviously bad)

Comment: If you're willing to use the multiprocessing module then this does appear to resolve the issue (I've updated my answer with a quick example otherwise identical to your original). I suspect that you won't find a way around it with the default Python threading if my assumption about the interaction with the GIL is correct.